# Does Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 install the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Does the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=26727) include the SQL Server when you install it? Cause after a long online search couln't found the answer.

Comment: I found the answer you were looking for by checking the README and install notes (which are linked to from the page you provided a link to). Per https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2974.microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-sp1-readme.aspx, "You can install SP1, even if you only have SQL Server Management Studio installed (where you don't have an instance of SQL Server installed yet)."

Answer (score 0):

It does not. You need to install the engine first. SP will just update it.

Comment: That is the reason I asked here, not able to find the link to install first the engine (2008 R2) Microsoft site sucks

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695

That's SQL Express. You have to purchase SQL from them to get access to the downloads for non-express versions. Once you purchase it, you can get the download through the MSOL website.

Comment: Thing is, I do have a MSDN account (my company does actually) and they do pay a anual fees or something similar. Through MS download site after logging in, it does offer only SQL 2014 and 2016 to download. Check the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/nJr7x

Comment: If you're downloading from MSDN, the SQL Server 2008 Service Pack XX downloads are full SQL installers with the SP prepackaged. My MSDN sub has access to SQL 2008  http://imgur.com/a/yQIEn

Comment: I don't understand then why my account doesn't offer the same...Could be because it's not a MSDN sub? Could be maybe Partner Account? don't really understand the MS licences and subscriptions sorry...

Comment: I have trouble with their licensing too. You'll have to contact MS.